# What is the physical description and $E$-$k$ plots for Dirac Semimetal, Weyl Semimetal, and Magnetic Weyl Semimetal?

Tags: fermions, dirac-equation, crystals, dispersion, weyl-semimetal

I've been trying to get a physical understanding of these three concepts, and any help would be appreciated. So far this is what I understand:

1. Dirac semi-metals have relativistic quasi-particles (with or without mass), hence the linear dispersion.
2. Weyl semi-metals are a special class of Dirac semi-metals with zero mass, and in odd-dimensional space (as such they come in opposite chirality).
3. Magnetic Weyl semi-metals are Weyl semi-metals with broken time-reversal symmetry.

Is this correct? If so, looking at a $E$-$k$ diagram, how would I distinguish between 1 and 2? I believe for Magnetic Weyl semi-metals, the Weyl nodes appear to two different $k$'s, so that is more easily identified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between Dirac and Weyl fermions both in particle physics and in condensed matter is that in the Weyl case there is only one allowed spin direction for a given ${\bf k}$ and in the Dirac case there are two. For example

$$
H_{\rm Weyl}= \kappa {\boldsymbol \sigma}\cdot {\bf p}
$$
while
$$
H_{\rm Dirac}=\kappa \left[\matrix{{\boldsymbol \sigma}\cdot {\bf p}&0\cr 0& -{\boldsymbol \sigma}\cdot {\bf p}}\right].
$$
The Dirac case is like a pair of coincident Weyl nodes, with opposite chirality, at a single point in the Brillouin zone. It can be continuously deformed into a pair of opposite chirality at different points.

Comment: So, if I understand it right, the degeneracy is broken for Weyl Fermions? Meaning now we have the two Dirac cones appearing at two different points on the E-k plot. In that case, how can I distinguish the two opposite spin states for Weyl Semimetals from the E-k plot? Thanks a lot for the help, I'm having a hard time visualizing the math for these physics.

Comment: There is no way to tell the two chiralities from just looking t the $E/k$ plots.